# maven dependencies to a parent project build path in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, parent, buildpath

I am using m2e. So I have two projects. When I right click on them both have maven enabled. So one of the projects is a parent project so it has many sub packages each sub package is correctly src\target, but not the parent itself. I have pom.xml for parent and all the children.

When I right click on these two projects then maven then update configuration. The maven repository gets added to the simple project but not to the one which is a parent of the rest. So what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform a `mvn install` for the artifacts to get installed in the repository, the "update project configuration" is similar to the `mvn eclipse:eclipse` goal of the [maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/index.html).

Comment: Artifacts are there in the repository. And they get added to the simple prj by update prj conf. But they don't get added to the parent project which has a pom along with several other packages each with their own pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks. I just switched to Netbeans and by just importing the project everything was done! Thanks anyways.